# Telegram webhook route not initializing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, telegram-bot

[According to the ReadMe](https://github.com/telegram-bot-rb/telegram-bot#routes-in-rails-app) telegram-bot suggests route helpers for webhooks. But if I place

```
telegram_webhook TelegramController
```

in the routes.rb file, then query:

```
bundle exec rake routes
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant TelegramController
```

Note: there is a controller, again suggested by the gem's README which defines the class as

```
class Telegram::WebhookController < Telegram::Bot::UpdatesController
```

what is the proper way to get the webhook functioning?